# Address list at billing step

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, billing-address

Hello Magento community this is my first question so go easy on me, I will try to be as accurate as possible but I am a noob front-end with Magento.

What I am trying to achieve is: when user buys virtual products only, which automatically skips second step of the checkout, display address list at the billing step if user has saved address.

**So far I managed to achieved this:**
[image]

**by adding:**

```
<item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="billing-address-list" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**Inside checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="billing-address-list" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Checkout/js/view/billing-address/list</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="payzen-payments" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Lyranetwork_Payzen/js/view/payment/payzen-payments</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Removes GiftCard Account section from Checkout/Payment step -->
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Removes Promo Code section from Checkout/Payment step -->
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Illicado_Checkout/js/view/billing-address-validation</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

**billing-address/list.html**

```
<div class="field addresses">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="billing-address-items">
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: elems, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko template: element.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make it work and also get rid of this weird second address list element which for some reason appears.